# initialize uint8_t array from txt file

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, txt, uint8t

I have, in a `.txt` file, a `uint8_t` array already formatted, like this:

```
0x4d, 0x5a, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,
0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40,
```

What I need is to initialize it from C++ like so:

```
static const uint8_t binary[] = { 0x4d, 0x5a, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, }
```

Honestly, I'm a bit new at C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the .txt file storing the hex values as bytes, or as 4 characters representing the hex values with literal commas and spaces?

If you're storing the actual hexadecimal values, the code becomes as simple as

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

// input file stream
std::ifstream is("MyFile.txt"); 

// iterators to start and end of file
std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> start(is), end; 

// initialise vector with bytes from file using the iterators
std::vector<uint8_t> numbers(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply need to include your text file at the place of array declaration:

```
static const uint8_t binary[] = {
#include "array.txt"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text file is shown *exactly* as you have shown, AND you want to initialize the array at *compile-time*, then you could simply `#include` the file, eg:

```cpp
static const uint8_t binary[] = {
#include "text.txt"
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to open the text file at runtime, such as with `std::ifstream`, read in its context and parse the byte values from it, and then allocate and populate your array dynamically, such as by using `std::vector`.